# R: importing data.table package namespace, unexplainable jump in memory consumption

Tags: r, memory, namespaces, data.table

I use data.table package inside my own package and I import data.table namespace in NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files.
In one of my functions I use data.table function to convert data.frame into data.table

```
dt <- data.table(df)
```

But when I call my function, at the point of calling data.table() memory usage jumps instantly and R just stops responding.
The code within the function works fine when I run it line by line and with low memory consumption.
Also, if I put library(data.table) within my function everything is fine. I was trying to avoid putting library(data.table) in my function and declare dependency instead. However, it seems something is going wrong that way. I am running R-2.14.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Can anybody explain what could be a reason, and how can I fix that (without using library(data.table) within my function)?

Comment: How do you do the import in the namespace and description files?

Comment: It is hard to diagnose the problem without a reproducible example. Can you provide the source for your package?

Answer (score 3):

Some random guesses in no particular order :

Try use the Imports or Depends field in DESCRIPTION only. I don't think you need to import in NAMESPACE as well, but I might be wrong. Why that would explain the memory use though, don't know.

What is `df`? Is it big or somehow recursive or strange in some way? Please provide `str(df)` to tell us something about it, if possible.

Try `as.data.table(df)` which is faster than `data.table(df)`. But it sounds like your problem is different to that.

Is your function call being called repeatedly? I can see why repeatedly converting `df` to `dt` would use up memory, but not why just calling `library(data.table)` would make that fast.

Try starting R with `R --vanilla` to ensure no `.Rdata` (which may include functions masking `data.table`'s) is being loaded on startup, amongst other things. If you have developed your own package then some kind of function name conflict, or the order of packages on the `search()` path sounds plausible.

Otherwise we'll need more information please. I don't recall anything similar to this happening to me, or being reported before.

And, which version of `data.table` are you using?  There is this bug fix in v1.8.1 on R-Forge (not yet on CRAN) :

> - Moved `data.table` setup code from `.onAttach` to `.onLoad` so that it is also run when `data.table` is simply `import`ed from within a package, fixing #1916 related to missing `data.table` options.

But if you are using 1.8.0 from CRAN, and are Importing (only) rather than Depending then I'd expect you to get an error about missing options rather than a jump in memory consumption.

Comment: I am using data.table v1.8.0. So if I import only, I should get an error message, but I don't. It seems that in this case some other data.table function is found in the search path and that one causes a big memory consumption. 
I have tried putting data.table under Depends and than everything works fine.
df is a data.frame with ~500000 rows and 4 columns, and when I run the code with data.table under Depends memory consumption is ~2 GB. However, when data.table is under Imports, memory consumption for the same code is ~40 GB (I have tried to run it on the server instead on my Mac)

Comment: Can you upgrade to 1.8.1? At least just to see if that bug fix fixes it. You say another data.table function is found in the search path, can you `find` it?

Comment: Upgrading to 1.8.1 fixed everything. Now it works normally for both Importing and Depending.

I don't know what was the issue with the old version when put under Import. It seems data.table was being created somehow although I could not find the data.table function in the search path?!:

cat(class(df))
> data.frame

find("data.table")
> character(0)

dt <- data.table(df)  *jump in memory

cat(class(dt))
> data.table data.frame

So data.table has been created, but when trying to use "[" function on the created dt, an error about missing options occurs.

Comment: If I provide missing options by:

options(datatable.nomatch=0)
options(datatable.verbose=F)

the code runs all the way through, does the job, but the memory consumption is 20X higher than normally.

Comment: Great. I assume in last comment you're talking about 1.8.0 not 1.8.1. Thanks for extra info. I can now reproduce this and have filed [bug#2014](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2014&group_id=240&atid=975) explaining what is going on. If you need to stay with 1.8.0 and Import only, then set `options(datatable.alloccol=100L)` too and the memory consumption problem should go away. Or, Depend instead or upgrade to 1.8.1. In your import field you could specify data.table version 1.8.1 or later. Thanks!